# Android Studio - Advisable Image Processing Library that works well with Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I feel like there is a necessity to ask this question because of the migration of Android Development from Eclipse to Android Studio. A good number of libraries (e.g. AChartEngine for Graphing in Android, among other graphing libraries for Android) also made their libraries available for Maven Dependencies in addition to the the old .jar file libraries that were used for Eclipse.

However, the situation is not the same for Image Processing Libraries as most of them are still using jars and are a bit of a trouble when you need to import them to Android Studio.

A famous open source library for image processing is OpenCV. I managed to import it to my Android Studio project thanks to some Stack Overflow answers. However, it seems as if statically initializing OpenCV for Android Studio is not that straightforward. Also, the import guide of OpenCV to Android Studio seem to be "outdated" as some of them call to create a folder under your "app" folder in Android Studio but I can't seem to make that. The case simply is that OpenCV requires a lot of work to import to Android Studio. Another issue is that there seems to be a lack of tutorial/guides on how to develop applications using OpenCV in Android.

Another Library I found was AndroidFastImageProcessing. It is another library for Image Processing that is available in Android but I can't import it to Android Studio as I needed `Android Support Repository` which wasn't available in Android Studio's SDK Manager (I only had the Support Library). And I am once again stunted in my progress as I can't seem to properly import an Image Processing Library Properly.

Now, I may be doing things wrong in importing - so if there's a new and updated way of importing OpenCV to Android Studio, kindly do place that in the answers, I'd be grateful. The same goes for AndroidFastImageProcessing - if there's a way to import it successfully in Android Studio, I'd love to know.

My main question is this: is there an Image Processing Library that can be easily imported to Android Studio? A tutorial/great documentation will merit plus points.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry but can the mods just move it there?

Comment: just copy past your question over there and delete this question. (-:

Comment: Okay nevermind I got it to work. I misread something on the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many native image processing libs available for android, but problem is lack of examples and tutorials , but you can certainly find many libs:

List of few most used :
1. AndroidJniBitmapOperations
2. javacv
3. Opencv

If u wanna work on NDK 
https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android

by far best is JAVACV - a java wapper for native opancv, this is growing well and with few useful tutorials and bunch of documentation you can start image processing like me in javacv ;)

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

Comment: Accept answer if you find helpful :)

Comment: I'm not done evaluating JavaCV yet because it seems to not have a lot of Android tutorials. However, it is interesting that it's already in Java.